# Ajax ToggleButtonExtender image does not display

Tags: asp.net, ajax, checkbox, togglebutton

I'am using AjaxToggleButtonExtender

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
  <asp:ToggleButtonExtender ID="ToggleButtonExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="CheckBox1" UncheckedImageUrl="~/assets/img/icon-img-up.png" ImageHeight="10" ImageWidth="40" CheckedImageUrl="~/assets/img/icon-img-down.png">
  </asp:ToggleButtonExtender>
```

But checkhed and unchecked image doesnt display.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code. js and css? :)

Comment: I have so much js and css codes :/ Using bootstrap.js.I thought about jquery crash.Deleted jqery links from page.Nothing changed.
An other question about this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720594/togglebuttonextender-image-display-issue)

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? also tried to make http request visible inside the console

Answer (score 0):

when resize the image using ImageHeight and ImageWidth, not the whole image was resized but only part of image was viewed by the togglebuttonextender according to the size that you entered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ToggleButtonExtender, you may need to size the container control to suit, or the images may not be visible.

For example, a `<td>` containing a checkbox will normally take a size that makes the checkbox visible, but a ToggleButtonExtender uses client-side code to render the images and may not take into account the constraints of the containing element. We have had the same visibility issue, where part or all of the image is missing.

We have solved it using a containing div, set to a sufficient size to allow the images to be seen:

```
<td>
    <div style="width: 30px">
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBooked" />
        <asp:ToggleButtonExtender ID="togbutBooked" 
            TargetControlID="chkBooked"
            UncheckedImageUrl="~/Images/toggle_off_small.png"
            CheckedImageUrl="~/Images/toggle_on_small.png">
        </asp:ToggleButtonExtender>
    </div>
</td>
```